# Create an xml file that wille be converted to an owl file (ontology)

Tags: xml

I have created an ontology (that containes classes, sub classes and properties) and now, i would like to creat an xml file to save information and this file will be converted to an owl file (our ontology).

How can I create an xml file, I mean the structor of this file ?

Thank you.

Comment: How have you created your ontology? In what format is it currently? Can you provide a sample of the saved ontology?

Comment: I have created it by using Protégé and it's format is Owl